# how to access props inside form

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
class EditProduct extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div>

                <ProductForm 
                  handleChange={this.handleChange}
                  clickHandle={this.clickHandle}
                  product={this.props.product}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {    
    return {
        product: state.ProductReducer.products[0]
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditProduct)

function ProductForm(props) {
 console.log("props from edit", props); // Here i can gets props
    return(
        <form>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="productid">Sku</label>
                <input type="email" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    id="sku" 
                    name="sku"
                    aria-describedby="skuHelp" 
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                    value={props.sku}
                    placeholder="Enter SKU"/>
           </div>
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT:**

> delProd: id => {…} editProd: id => {…} history: {length: 25, action:
>   "PUSH", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
>           location: {pathname: "/", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "hwy1de"}
>           match: {path: "/", url: "/", isExact: true, params: {…}}
>           products: Array(1)
>           0: {sku: "SD", productName: "prd", description: "des", duration: "231", id: "nUkHoRev"}
>           length: 1

I am trying to list value inside the form but it does not display however I am getting value inside props

if I try inside to add props.products[0].sku it says its not defined obviously it is not defined until there is anything inside products. How can I use same form for edit and add product. Please guide thanks a lot in advance

Comment: value={props.sku},it wont work, shouldn't be props.product?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
  <form>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="productid">Sku</label>
            <input type="email" 
                className="form-control" 
                id="sku" 
                name="sku"
                aria-describedby="skuHelp" 
                onChange={props.handleChange}
                defaultValue={props.products && props.products.sku}
                placeholder="Enter SKU"/>
       </div>
```

Hope this will resolve

Answer (score 1):

Here you pass **`product`**

```
<div>

                <ProductForm 
                  handleChange={this.handleChange}
                  clickHandle={this.clickHandle}
                  product={this.props.product}
                />
            </div>
```

and here you are getting products? Is there something got missing in your code?

```
console.log("props from edit", props);
```

Comment: delProd: id => {…}
    editProd: id => {…}
    history: {length: 25, action: "PUSH", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
    location: {pathname: "/", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "hwy1de"}
    match: {path: "/", url: "/", isExact: true, params: {…}}
    products: Array(1)
    0: {sku: "SD", productName: "prd", description: "des", duration: "231", id: "nUkHoRev"}
    length: 1
This is what i am getting while consoling props